# Setup Azure External Endpoint to access to a Web API

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, endpoint

I have 10 virtual machines setup in Azure and configured with a load balancer. I've deployed a RESTFul web service and I can access to it internally through API Calls. The calls get routed to one of the 10 machines and everything works perfectly.

However I want to configure an external endpoint that allows me to access to the API from the internet and keep redirecting the calls to one of the 10 machines. I haven't seen documentation or steps on how to do that. Could someone explain how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either by adding an internet facing load balancer (see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-internet-overview)) or front-ending with an [application gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction) (optionally with WAF) your http traffic and load balancing.

Comment: Just to confirm. The application gateway would be like a web app that will route the external request to the Internal Virtual Machines?. Note: I do not require that subsequences call end up going to the same machine

Comment: yes App Gateway will do load balancing for http/s traffic to your 10 vms on which your web service is running.

Comment: Awesome! Making your answer as valid :)